# How to retrieve logged user image from AD?

Tags: asp.net

> I had my code to retrieve logged user details , every thing is OK but
>   i cannot retrieve the user image .

```
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher();
        searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        searcher.Filter = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "(sAMAccountName={0})", Environment.UserName);
        //SearchResult findUser = searcher.FindOne();
        foreach (SearchResult findUser in searcher.FindAll())
        {
            if (findUser != null)
            {
                DirectoryEntry user = findUser.GetDirectoryEntry();
                string userName = user.Properties["displayName"].Value.ToString();
                string departement = user.Properties["Department"].Value.ToString();
                string title = user.Properties["title"].Value.ToString();
                string[] rt = new string[] { Login, userName, Email, Mobile };

                Lbl_User.Text = userName;
                Lbl_Administrative.Text = departement;
                Lbl_Position.Text = title;

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The binary image should be stored in property called thumbnailPhoto.

```
      var photo = user.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"];
      if (photo != null) {
        byte[] buffer = (byte[])photo.Value;
        //var bitmap = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(buffer, false));
        //bitmap.Save(@"c:\test.bmp");
      }
```

Now, given the fact that you tagged question as asp.net you'll have to write generic handler (.ashx) for retrieving the image. This handler should write content of

```
      photo.Value
```

into response output stream and set content type to image/bmp

In your control/page just reference the handler like

```
<img src="/GenericHandler.ashx" alt="My image" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just taken your code and made a method out of it just to retrieve the image. You would need to refactor it, to either get only the byte[] or thw whole image.

```
//add this
using System.Drawing;

static Image GetPhotoFromAD(string userName)
{
    DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher();
    searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
    searcher.Filter = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "(sAMAccountName={0})", userName);
    //SearchResult findUser = searcher.FindOne();
    foreach (SearchResult findUser in searcher.FindAll())
    {
       if (findUser != null)
       {
          byte[] photodata = findUser.Properties["jpegPhoto"].Value as byte[];
          using (MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream(photodata))
          {
             return Bitmap.FromStream(str);
          }
        }
    }
}
```

If you only want the raw data, the important bit is `byte[] photodata = user.Properties["jpegPhoto"].Value as byte[];`

Comment: the userName parameter isn't used?  was intention to replace 'Environment.UserName'?